# Spring MVC JSON serialization @JsonSerialize is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

Using Spring Boot, Spring MVC and returning POJO with List. `Date` field is not serialized when field annotated with my custom JsonSerializer (@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)).

**`JsonSerializer.serialize` is not called.**

How can I get this working - to force Jackson to call my custom Serializers?
I can extend ObjectMapper and set something but so far nothing worked.

I've tried to annotate getters but no success here.

Using Spring 4, Jackson 2.4.4, included all jackson dependencies (databind, annotations, core). I've included Spring OXM as well.

DateTimeSerializer class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class DateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(DateUtil.toCzechDateTime(date));
    }
}
```

DateUtil.toCzechDateTime is my own method and works okay - returns a String which I want.

Comment: can you post your DateTimeSerializer class?

Comment: Here it goes, I've edited my post.

Comment: Also, can you provide your POJO where you use `@JsonSerialize`?

Comment: One common problem is accidentally using Jackson 1.x annotations with Jackson 2.x `ObjectMapper` -- so make sure versions match (`com.fasterxml.jackson` means 2.x, `org.codehaus.jackson` is 1.x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workarounds:

You can implement your own `ObjectMapper` class and set date format globally. (Edit below code accordingly)

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();
        super.setDateFormat(df);
    }
```

Or you can add `DateUtil.toCzechDateTime(date)` to your POJO in a getter and ignore the original getter.  And return the new getter using `@JsonProperty("date")`.

Comment: Yes, I've done it this way. Always there is some workaround and there is no time to thinking about it forever. Thanks.